# Is there a 3d walkthrough tour of the beis hamikdash online?

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, beis-hamikdash

I have seen a few very brief videos that present 3d walk through tours of the beis hamikdash (usually the 2nd bayis). I would like to know if there are any extensive, thorough such videos available for free online.

Comment: Not what you are looking for, but of noted interest:  http://harhakodesh.co.il/tour/  (It's in hebrew)

Answer (score 3):

There is a [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0XuZTT2aVY) demonstrating a Minecraft project of the first Bet Hamikdash, as well as of the Mishkan, as a project by Rabbi Swigard's class in Harkam Hillel Hebrew Academy, 2012.

Here is also a link to the Minecraft [skin](http://adf.ly/I4QPw) and [map](http://adf.ly/I4QCm). In this way, if you have Minecraft, you can walk through the Bet Hamikdash yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for:
http://jerusalem.com/tour/jewish_temple_3D/web

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Rivky. Thanks for the answer. Consider taking the following short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site to learn more. Hope you choose to stick around the site.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21719)

Comment: @sabbahillel the question was *for the link*.

Comment: Link down.......

Answer (score 1):

Moshiach.com has an [interactive walk-through](http://moshiach.com/temple/tour/) of (what I'm pretty sure is) the Third Temple.

It doesn't seem to work properly on Chrome, but works fine on Firefox.

Comment: Link down......